# JMS client that doesn't terminate

Tags: java, jms

We have a JMS client that needs to sit idle until it receives a message. When it receives a message, it will execute some functionality and then go back to an idle state. My question is, what is the best way to ensure that the client stays up and running? Is it good practice to let the JMS client software handle this or do we need to run the software as a service on the host machine (and/or do something else)? We are currently relying on the JMS client software as it seems to keep a thread active with the open connection but I am unsure if this is best practice. We use ActiveMQ as our message broker and for the client software.

**Edit: Added code sample**

Below is an example of how the client stays up using the JMS client connection:

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Session;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class JmsTestWithoutClose implements MessageListener {

    private final Connection connection;
    private final Session session;
    private final MessageConsumer consumer;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        JmsTestWithoutClose test = new JmsTestWithoutClose("<username>", "<password>", "tcp://<host>:<port>");
        // if you uncomment the line below, the program will terminate
        // if you keep it commented, the program will NOT terminate
        // test.close();
        System.out.println("Last line of main method...");
    }

    public JmsTestWithoutClose(String username, String password, String url) throws JMSException {
        // create connection and session
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(username, password, url);
        this.connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        this.session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createTopic("Topic_Name");
        consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        consumer.setMessageListener(this);
    }

    public void close() throws JMSException {
        session.close();
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // process the message
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the current client implementation fulfilling your requirements?  If so, I would not change it.  If the current client implementation is *not* fulfilling your requirements then I would change it. Changing software which is working without a problem and fulfilling your needs (and with no clear foreseeable problems) simply to adhere to a "best practice" is almost certainly not the best investment of resources.

Ultimately the behavior of the application is up to the application itself.  I don't see how running the application as a service or doing anything else external to the application would actually force it to stay up and running properly while it listens/waits for messages.  It would be a bug if the application were programmed, for example, to use the JMS API and create a MessageListener (i.e. the class responsible for receiving messages asynchronously) and then exit without actually waiting for messages. Running such an application as a service so that the OS keeps restarting it after it incorrectly exits wouldn't be a good solution.

Having a properly written client is the best practice. Propping it up with some external mechanism is bad practice.

The sample code you provided is poorly written and has some clear problems:

1. The `Connection` and `Session` objects fall out of scope which means they can never be properly closed. Eventually those objects will be garbage collected by the JVM. This is improper resource management.
2. The only reason the application doesn't terminate completely is due to the way the ActiveMQ 5.x client is implemented (i.e. the open connection blocks the JVM process from terminating). This implementation detail is not part of the public contract provided by the JMS API and should therefore not be relied upon. If you were to use a different JMS client implementation, e.g. the ActiveMQ Artemis core JMS client, the application *would* terminate completely as soon as `main()` exited.

To fix this, your `main()` method should wait after creating the `JmsTestWithoutClose` instance. There are lots of ways to do this in Java:

1. Use a `while` loop with a `Thread.sleep()` where the loop's condition can be modified as needed to allow the application to exit.
2. Use an object specifically designed for thread coordination like [`java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Using a `CountDownLatch` the `main()` method can invoke `await()` and when the application is finished processing messages the `MessageListener` implementation, for example, can invoke `countDown()`
3. Use a `while` loop reading input from the console and only continue when a special string is input (e.g. *exit*).

In any case, it's important that the application close all of the resources it created (e.g. sessions, connections, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the response. It fulfills our needs in our DEV environment and we will test it in the other ones but we still are not sure if it is considered best practice or not. We like to move things into production once they pass testing in the other environments and once we have confirmed we are following best practices (or have a very good reason to deviate from best practices).

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional details. Hope that helps.

Comment: In your update you wrote that it would be a bug if the application were programmed to create a MessageListener and then exit without actually waiting for messages. My question is about the last part of that sentence. What is the proper way to wait for messages? When I run a test app from Eclipse my main method completes but the process doesn't terminate (terminate button is still enabled), presumably because I never closed the connection. Is keeping the connection open a good way to keep a program running and waiting for messages?

Comment: I added a code sample to further explain what I mean by using the JMS client connection to keep the program running. Take a look at the comment above the commented out "test.close()" in the main method. Thanks!

Comment: Keeping the connection open is **not** a good way to keep the program running. I've updated my answer with additional details to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I put short code up there to make it easy to read. We do create MessageConsumers with MessageListeners in our actual production code. But, currently the parent object does eventually fall out of scope, and that is where my problem resides. What is the best way to keep the program running? A loop that constantly checks for some kind of signal to stop? A prompt to read input from a user? The loop seems like it would unnecessarily waste CPU and the input prompt looks like it could get accidental input from a user causing the program to terminate.

Comment: Update your question with more realistic code and I'll be able to comment.

Comment: OK, I updated the question with a more realistic example. The MessageListener and MessageConsumer are now registered, but the object still falls out of scope and is therefore expecting the open connection to keep the program running.

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Your first and third options are what we have played with and they have worked fine for us. Thank you for confirming that those are considered good solutions to this problem.