# MessageListener for ActiveMQ Artemis consumer is not receiving messages

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I am migrating from ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.18.1 to ActiveMQ Artemis.

I updated my producer and consumer code as per documentation. I could get my producer to send messages. But the consumer app is exiting even though I have attached a `MessageListener` to it. I expected my `MessageListener` to be always up and running. What am I missing?

```java
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.util.Properties;


public class Consumer1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String topicName = "jms/topic/default_EventTopic";
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
        properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://localhost:61616");

        Context context = new InitialContext(properties);
        ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
        try {
            connection.setClientID("SampleConnection");
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            final Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup(topicName);
            final MessageConsumer consumer = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, "EventConsumer");

            connection.start();
            consumer.setMessageListener(message -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Type " + message.getStringProperty("type"));
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        } catch (final JMSException | NamingException cause) {
            System.out.println("Error while creating Message Consumer");
            cause.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you using this same code with ActiveMQ "Classic"?

Comment: I made two changes from classic code  1. Changed - context.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory"); to  context.lookup(ConnectionFactory");  2. Updated  INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY to - "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory";

Comment: For what it's worth, your application would be more portable if you externalized the JNDI properties into a `jndi.properties` file on your classpath. Then you could just update the file without having to modify and rebuild your application.

Comment: yes Justin. I had them in jndi.properties only, but for simplicity for posting question, I had them in the code itself here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a JMS `MessageListener` it will receive messages asynchronously in its own thread (invoked by the JMS client implementation). In your case you need to prevent `main` from exiting and stopping your application because when that happens the `MessageListener` will be terminated.

The only reason the application didn't terminate completely with ActiveMQ "Classic" is due to the way the OpenWire JMS client is implemented (i.e. the open connection blocks the JVM process from terminating). This implementation detail is not part of the public contract provided by the JMS API and should therefore not be relied upon. Now that you've switched to the ActiveMQ Artemis core JMS client the application terminates completely as soon as `main` exits.

That said, you *can continue* to use the OpenWire JMS client with ActiveMQ Artemis if you like. ActiveMQ Artemis supports the OpenWire protocol.

It's worth noting that this is a relatively common problem with JMS applications using a `MessageListener`. See here:

- [How does the MessageListener running in JMS? Can it load messages in the queue in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413491/how-does-the-messagelistener-running-in-jms-can-it-load-messages-in-the-queue-i)
- [How do I keep my JMS message listener listening indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750018/how-do-i-keep-my-jms-message-listener-listening-indefinitely)
- [No onMessage events on Runtime (Java JMS MessageListener on Oracle Queue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223746/no-onmessage-events-on-runtime-java-jms-messagelistener-on-oracle-queue)
- [JMS client that doesn't terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53511049/jms-client-that-doesnt-terminate)

Comment: I see. But this used to work automatically in ActiveMQ classic i.e. main method was not exiting if I have MessageListener attached to Consumer.

Comment: That's just the way the ActiveMQ "Classic" implementation works. That behavior is not defined in the JMS specification therefore it's not required.

Comment: Thanks again for such a detailed response Justin.